# Using jq with bash variables results in error

Tags: bash, jq

I have the following json file

```
{
  "result": {
    "run": {
      "runtime": "runc"
    },
    "software": {
      "runc": "1.1.2",
      "kata": "1.3.7"
    }
  }
}
```

I can extract the runtime info using this

```
# jq -r '.result.software .runc' input.json
1.1.2
```

However, if I try to extract the version number dynamically, it does not work (The runtime can change)

```
# runtime=$(jq -r '.result.run .runtime' input.json)
# jq --arg key "$runtime" '.result.software .[$key]' 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.result.software .[$key]                  
jq: 1 compile error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combined dot notation only works with literal names. Use `.result.software[$key]` instead:

```bash
runtime="$(jq -r '.result.run.runtime' input.json)"
jq -r --arg key "$runtime" '.result.software[$key]'
```

```
1.1.2
```

If the dynamic value is always a result of evaluating the same JSON file, and you don't need that value elsewhere in the shell script, you can resolve that internally and reduce the script to just one call to jq:

```bash
jq -r '.result.run.runtime as $key | .result.software[$key]' input.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/e2GAKh6m32C)

Or without using variables at all:

```bash
jq -r '.result | .software[.run.runtime]' input.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/G_OJKTTiGr6)

Note: Never use double quotes to inject data into code. `--arg` is always a better choice.